# Is there a recommended distance between fasteners on sole plates?

Tags: basement, fastener, sill

We've just started installing pressure treated 2x4s as sole plates in our 5 year old basement. We drove 3 nails into each 8' plate, one at each end (around 3 or 4 inches in) and one somewhere at the center.

For smaller lengths, we may use two, or in the case or plates next to doors that in turn abut walls, there probably won't be room for more than one.

I can't find a reference that specifies how many such fasteners are needed per unbroken length, or a recommended / required distance between such fasteners.

Are we doing right with this many fasteners to a plate?

If it helps, we're in East-Central Minnesota. And I'm using 22-caliber powder-actuated 2.5" nails, if that makes a difference to the recommendation.

Comment: Are you putting anything between the sole plate and the concrete?  Wood in direct contact with concrete is not a good idea, even if the wood is pressure treated. They make foam gaskets (I believe they are called "sill plate gaskets"), that can be put between the bottom plate and the concrete.

Comment: @Tester101, nope, haven't used gaskets for the first 3 plates we installed. Still have many more to go; I'll make sure this is done. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, in MN, I'd use steel studs (and have). That said to answer the question...it doesn't sound like these are load bearing walls, so given that, I think it's likely 'whatever keeps the wall in place' will suffice.

Comment: @DA01, yep. I originally figured we would use metal studs (per your excellent answer to one of my previous questions). But then, there's something satisfying about cutting down wood - the smell, the sawdust, slamming nails into the material, the actual honest-to-goodness feeling of having done something "substantial"... that just about feels right :)

Comment: @alt I'd agree...just don't smell the treated stuff that much...not good for you. :)

Comment: @DA01 I read your post about your wall system and it's very interesting. It was unclear though whether you filled the wall bays with fiberglass, something else or nothing. Also, is GP's DensArmor a vapor barrier and how does it look painted? Some people don't like green board because the wax coating doesn't paint well. If I was going to go unconventional (besides wood framing) nowadays, I'd take a hard look at the insulation companies' wall systems. But I guess the real test of any wall method or system is to come back 50 years later open it up and see how it did.

Comment: @rand I used EPS for insulation. Densarmor is not a vapor barrier. It's sheetrock. It painted OK, though note it has a very slight texture to it. In hindsight, I should have skim coated the entire board--not just the joints. Note that the method I outlined is the method Building Science Corp recommends (and the US DOE suggests).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming none of these are structural shear walls since shot pins are inappropriate for such use. There is some arbitrary lateral load that interior partitions are supposed to resist, it's only 5 or 10 psf from memory, I can't find the reference at the moment. I'm not sure what the shot pins are rated for either. So without any more specific data, I would judge that a 4 foot spacing should be about right. There's really no need for doubled fasteners at the ends, as long as there's at least one good shot at the ends. You do not want to place shots too close together, the second shot weakens the first.

There is some minimum spacing determined by the shot pin manufacturer to achieve a certain rated strength. This is usually outlined in so called "ICBO Reports" or similar. I would guess a 5-6" minimum spacing would be safe. The only reason to place shots this close is if the first one spalled out the concrete.

Comment: thanks! I've got one shot at each end of the 8' plate, and I don't think I'll put two fasteners closer than a foot at least to each other. I've edited my original question to correct the mistaken "two shots at each end" text. And these aren't structural, just interior non-load-bearing walls.